# deploy contracts, invalid number of parameters

Tags: truffle, openzeppelin, truffle-deployment

need a little help. I'm frustrated with this.

here's my sol. very simple

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract EkoToken is ERC20 {

    constructor(uint _initialSupply) ERC20("EkoToken", "EKOT") public {
        _mint(msg.sender, _initialSupply * (10 ** decimals())); 
    }
}
```

here's my 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
const EkoToken = artifacts.require("EkoToken");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(EkoToken, 1000000);
};
```

how is it when I deploy this using truffle migrate, I have this error

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"EkoToken" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 2 expected 1!.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works. first i changed the deployer to this

```
const EkoToken = artifacts.require("EkoToken");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(EkoToken, 1000000);
};
```

then it gives me this error

```
Error:  * Deployment Failed *

"EkoToken" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!
```

then I switch it back to this

```
const EkoToken = artifacts.require("EkoToken");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(EkoToken, 1000000);
};
```

now it's working. is truffle not refreshed or something?

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the migration?
I have found that specifying reset:

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

cures a great many of these issues ;)